# UEFI dual boot won't dual boot

Tags: release-loki, dual-boot, uefi, microsoft-windows, encryption

I have a work laptop that had an encrypted partition with Windows 7 and I wanted to dual boot it with Loki. I installed Loki, but during the installation process it told me that I couldn't install it with UEFI without damaging the MBR or something or another, I can't recall. So I went back and partitioned it manually by shrinking the windows partition (within windows) than restarted the installer and made a swap, boot and home partition for Loki and installed Loki. The installation went fine and Loki runs perfectly, but when I boot the computer, I can't choose between Loki and Windows, so I can't boot into Windows anymore, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The fact that Loki is warning you about damaging the MBR suggests that Windows 7 was installed in BIOS mode not UEFI, otherwise it would be using GPT. Can you verify that your laptop is actually booting into UEFI and not BIOS?

Comment: You were right, I checked a secure mode is disabled.

Comment: This is not a elementaryOS issue, you need to understand what MBR, GPT, BIOS, EFI/UEFI, etc means first if you are going to dual-boot to keep both OS working

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but have you tried this?
[Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

It worked for me in previous problems i had

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work, unfortunetaly

Answer (score 0):

I had boot problems too, but in my case I could only boot Windows. I recommed you to try [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). Once installed, it should recognize all your OSes and let you choose which one to boot.

Comment: This didn't work for me either, because I found out I don't have a EFI-bootpartition.

Comment: You could try this in a terminal: "sudo update-grub" and see if that fixes the problem. When executing this command, you're telling grub to rescan your partitions in search of any OSes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should try to unhide your grub menu.

1. Open `/etc/default/grub` as sudo
2. Comment the line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` (put a # in the
   beginning)
3. Set `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu` (instead of hidden)
4. Open terminal and do: `sudo update-grub`
5. Reboot and you should see Grub menu. Select Windows and see if
   it boots.

If it doesn't boot, you should repair your Windows MBR. There is a comprehensive guide here: https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-uefi-boot/

And after repairing your Windows MBR, you need [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to get Elementary to boot and then again, you need to unhide your grub menu with the steps i described above.

This happens to me everytime i install Elementary in a Windows 10 UEFI dual-boot. I have to repair Windows MBR, run boot-repair and unhide Grub from Elementary. It may seem boring and time-consuming, but you can do it under 20 minutes.